# Convergence of the following numerical series

Tags: real-analysis

I'm asked to find:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}}{n^{1/n + 3/2}}$$

I just have no idea which test to use for this. It looks like a limit comparison test problem (i.e. choose some $b_n$ and then calculate $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n}$) but I'm not clear about what to do next. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Do a Limit Comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n}$. The bottom of your expression is $e^{1/n}n^{3/2}$. The  $n^{1/n}$ which looks scary has limit $1$.

**Detail:** Let $a_n$ be the $n$-th term. Then 
$$\frac{a_n}{1/n}=\frac{1}{n^{1/n}} \frac{n\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}}{n^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}\frac{n^{3/2}\sqrt{1-1/\sqrt{n}}}{n^{3/2}} .$$
This clearly $\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, so by the Limit Comparison Test our series diverges.

Comment: Thanks! I don't really understand what you mean by the bottom of my expression though, which expression exactly?

Comment: Your expression is $\frac{\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}}{n^{1/n+3/2}}$. The bottom is $n^{1/n+3/2}$. I had a typo which made it harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

We neglect $\sqrt n$ on face of $n$ at $\infty$ so
$$\frac{\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}}{n^{1/n + 3/2}}\sim_\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/n + 1}}\sim_\infty \frac{1}{n}$$
so the given series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.